# SQL Server - How to query the set of maximum numbers from a list of numbers from top to bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Best way to explain this would be through an example. Let's say I have this simple 2 column table:

```
Id | Score
1  | 10
2  | 5
3  | 20
4  | 15
5  | 20
6  | 25
7  | 30
8  | 30
9  | 10
10 | 40
```

The query should return the IDs of each item where the max score changed. So, from the top, 10 would be the top score since item 1 has 10 the first time through but then on item 3 it has a score of 20 so it just had a new max score and this continues until the bottom of the table. So eventually, the query will result to:

```
1, 3, 6, 7, 10
```

I tried doing a [**Cursor**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) and loop through the table but I was wondering if there was a much simple way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Is Score always increasing? Then you can use a simple GROUP BY.

Comment: No, the score can go up and down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution (SQL2012+):

```
SELECT v.MaxScore, MIN(v.Id) AS FirstId
FROM (
    SELECT *, MAX(t.Score) OVER(ORDER BY t.Id ASC) AS MaxScore
    FROM @Table AS t
) v
GROUP BY v.MaxScore
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b01efefd7870a2c7e1e8d41a6abb29f6)**

Answer (score 3):

one more version,works for versions >= 2008,you can remove apply to make it work for 2005 as well

```
;with cte
(Id , Score)
as
(
select 1  , 10  union all
select 2  , 5   union all
select 3  , 20  union all
select 4  , 15  union all
select 5  , 20  union all
select 6  , 25  union all
select 7  , 30  union all
select 8  , 30  union all
select 9  , 10  union all
select 10 , 40
)
select min(id)
from
cte  c2
cross apply
(select case when score -(select max(score) from cte c1 where  c1.id<=c2.id )=0 
  then 1 else 0 end) b(val)
where val=1
group by Score
```

**Output:**

```
1
3
6
7
10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do a `MIN` on the id with a `GROUP BY Score`. Like this:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) FROM table GROUP BY Score
```

Comment: You want `MIN(Id)`.

Comment: @jarlh : Sorry I meant MIN

Answer (score 0):

Using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function, that returns prev value of score:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id int, Score int)

INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES
(1  , 10),
(2  , 10),
(3  , 20),
(4  , 20),
(5  , 20),
(6  , 25),
(7  , 30),
(8  , 30),
(9  , 30),
(10 , 40)

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        LAG(t.Score, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id) AS PrevScore
    FROM @Table AS t
) AS p
WHERE p.Score <> p.PrevScore OR p.PrevScore IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out.

Comment: This gives me the last score of each item so this isn't really what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: (plus one from me) I copy-pasted from this solution DECLARE and INSERT statements for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  declare @scores varchar(max) 
  select @scores = isnull(@scores+',','')+convert(varchar,min(id)) 
  from #temp group by score
  select @scores
```